# Proverb/ expression/word for getting pepped up about stranger's cause

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

We have a saying "Abdullah gets all super pepped up in a stranger's Wedding" which means a person gets absolutely excited about some one else's cause which he logically isn't concerned with. Do we have any equivalent in English.

Normally any person wouldn't get as excited as much as the groom & bride, the parents and all those involved in the wedding. But this unrelated person/stranger gate crashes the wedding and gets too much involve and too excited about everything thats happening as those it is his wedding. It is as though you shouldn't get involved (physically or emotionally) and help others where it is not warranted or where you are not invited

Comment: Sounds like a _'busy meddling fiend'_. Henry IV Part II, (III, 3). [Shakespeare](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php?link=con&searchtype=exact&works[]=henry6p2&keyword1=meddling&sortby=WorkName&pleasewait=1&msg=sr)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to render this idea in English:

> She was so excited that you would think it was her wedding.

I could not find a reference in a dictionary, but Google Books revealed [a few of instances from novels](https://www.google.ch/search?tbm=bks&hl=fr&q=%22you%20would%20think%20it%20was%20her%20wedding%22) of the romantic genre.

Comment: It would be more "She was so excited that you would think it was her bff's wedding.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Since "unwelcome" is key, (U.S.) English speakers might say horn in (perhaps antiquated), butt in, or cut in, as in "She's always cutting in."  This calls to mind the current phrase "stay in your lane," which could be here, "she tends to be out of her lane."  Also: "party-crasher" or "wedding-crasher" might be used *if* the metaphor will be understood in context.

A similar phrase is "bandwagon-jumper," originally from the wagon that carries a band in a parade.  It has a similar connotation, someone who's overly enthusiastic, just looking for the current trend.
(Sports fans have their version, more disparaging: a "front-runner" roots only once the team is doing well.)

Comment: It is more of unwelcomed-unsolicited-orchestrator, but you cannot use it in an sentence. Bandwagon-jumper is when there is free to jump on bandwagon which this is a private occassion/ceremony/party/affair.

Comment: "Bandwagon jumper" is similar in implying the person is after excitement, as opposed to genuine interest.  In your phrase, if "unwelcomed" makes me wonder why the person's involvement would be allowed --?

Comment: ... perhaps I was too literal, have edited answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Basking in reflected glory

Not sure if it fits.

Basking in reflected glory (BIRGing) is a self-serving cognition whereby an individual associates themselves with known successful others such that the winner's success becomes the individual's own accomplishment.
[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basking_in_reflected_glory)

bask in the reflected glory
: to experience self-gratification on the basic[sic] of the success of someone with whom one is associated
parents who bask in the reflected glory of their children
[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bask%20in%20the%20reflected%20glory)

bathe/bask in reflected glory 
get attention and fame not because of something you have done but through the success of somebody else connected to you: 
She wasn’t happy to bathe in the reflected glory of her daughter’s success, as she wanted to succeed on her own.
[dictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bask+in+reflected+glory)

bask/bathe in reflected glory
to feel successful and admired for something, despite the fact that you did not achieve it yourself but were only connected to it in some way:
[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bask-bathe-in-reflected-glory)

The parents of the spouses, or the bridesmaids or groomsmen might bask in the reflected glory of the married couple?

Comment: Although this is new to me and sure an addition to my vocabulary. But this does not contribute to the query. It actually means an overzealous stranger indulging/contributing to a cause where he/she is uninvited, unnecessary. Similar to I being a total stranger gatecrash at your wedding and start being emotional like your parents and ecstatic like your best buddy for you which is uncalled-for something like misplaced priorities.